# SQL insert new row with the same data apart from one or two fields

Tags: sql, insert

Is there a quicker way to copy the same content of a row in a table with modifying only few fields?

Dealing with 5-10 fields is ok but when you have about 50 while some of the data MUST be NULL you cant have shortcuts but to manually enter the data.

So lets say we have: F1, f2, f3... f40 where we want to change the data for f3 and f15 while f7 and f10 must be NULL.

What would be the quickest insert script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I just use the "select top 1000 rows from table" feature in SSMS, this will generate a chunk that will give you all the fields.  You might end up with something like

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [F1],
    [F2],
    [F3],
    ....
    [F50]
  FROM [database].[dbo].[table]
```

Then modify the fields you want, bound it with a where clause from the data you want to copy, and replace your Fx field with the data you want.  Then use INSERT INTO and your select.

Comment: Why not just right click > Script Table As > INSERT To > New Query Editor Window to get half way there instead of just a quarter of the way?

Comment: if you take a look at the code that produces, you would still have to add a select statement or you would have to plug in every value by hand, which is what OP is trying to avoid.